# Laravel: How to send value from Controller to Model?

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-8

How can I send a value from Controller to Model and how to receive the value in the Model.

I let above a picture of my database tables.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQEGw.png)

Example: If I enter in the input ***3 action movies***

```
 $category=category::with('film')->where('name','=','Action')->first();
```

> Film model:3

```
class film extends Model{
    protected $table = "film";  //Para nao dar o erro de singular e plural
    protected $primaryKey = 'film_id';
    public $timestamps = false;
    use HasFactory;
    protected $sql=['film_id', 'title', 'release_year'];

    public function category(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(category::class,'film_category', 'film_id', 'category_id');
   }   
}
```

> Category model:

```
class category extends Model{
    protected $table = "category";
    protected $primaryKey = 'category_id';
    public $timestamps = false;
    use HasFactory;
    protected $sql=['category_id','name'];

    public function film(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(film::class,'film_category', 'category_id', 'film_id');
    }
}
```

NOTE: I realized that I need to add in the front of the Category model

***->take(3)***

But I don't know how to send the value(3 or other else) via $category query.

Comment: I think you have to add limit(3) to the relation. Also it could be useful if you post the relations, for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller Side

```
$category=category::with('film')->where('name','=','Action')->film->category($value);
```

Model Side

```
    public function category($value){
        return $this->belongsToMany(category::class,'film_category', 'film_id', 'category_id')->where('foo', $value);
   }
```

Comment: @Richard how does this answer achieve your goal of limiting the query to a certain number of results? I see no code here that would do any sort of limiting.

Comment: @miken32 if you can follow the issue tell the end, you would see how this solves his problem

Answer (score 1):

You can simply put conditions in the closure of the "film" relationship on the controller to get 3 action movies or any number of movies.

Controller:

```
$limit = 3;
$category=category::with(['film'=>function($query)use($limit)
{
    $query->limit($limt);

}])->where('name','=','Action')->first();
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution also works :)